# Reading Messy SAS Data

Tags: sas

How can I read this -

```
    C 303 102 140 B 293 C 399 B 450 233 456
450 A 289 282 555
```

like this -

```
Group Score
    C 303 
    C 102 
    C 140 
    B 293 
    C 399 
    B 450 
    B 233 
    B 456
    B 450 
    A 289 
    A 282 
    A 555
```

In SAS? I have tried the @'character' column pointer, which I cant seem to get right. This is the code so far :( -

```
data OUTCOMES;
infile 'testscores.txt';
input @'C' SCORES; Run;
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that generates those data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coo:

The double ampersand (@@) operator for held input looks good [pun intended] for scanning inputs across line boundaries.

Construct an example external data file:

```
filename haveFile temp;

data _null_;
  file haveFile;
  put "    C 303 102 140 B 293 C 399 B 450 233 456";
  put "450 A 289 282 555";
run;
```

Read from the file, one token at a time.

```
data have ;
  attrib
    token group length=$10
    score length=8
  ;

  retain group;

  infile haveFile ;

  input token @@;
  score = input (token, ?? 12.);  * check if token can be interpreted as a number, the ?? modifier prevents errors and notes in the log;

  if missing (score) and token ne '.' then 
    group = token;
  else
    output;
run;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It's a steep learning curve and this certainly helps with overcoming it.